# Selectively disabling WebControl elements

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I have an ASP.Net MasterPage with a PlaceHolder element.
The contents of the PlaceHolder can be viewed in two modes: read-write, and read-only.

To implement read only, I wanted to disable all inputs inside the PlaceHolder.
I decided to do this by recursively looping through the controls collection of the PlaceHolder, finding all the ones which inherit from WebControl, and setting `control.Enabled = false;`.

Here's what I originally wrote:

```
private void DisableControls(Control c)
{
    if (c.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(WebControl)))
    {
        WebControl wc = c as WebControl;
        wc.Enabled = false;
    }

    //Also disable all child controls.
    foreach (Control child in c.Controls)
    {
        DisableControls(child);
    }
}
```

This worked fine, and all controls are disabled... But then the requirement changed ;)
NOW, we want to disable all controls *except* ones which have a certain CssClass.

So, my first attempt at the new version:

```
private void DisableControls(Control c)
{
    if (c.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(WebControl)))
    {
        WebControl wc = c as WebControl;
        if (!wc.CssClass.ToLower().Contains("someclass"))
            wc.Enabled = false;
    }

    //Also disable all child controls.
    foreach (Control child in c.Controls)
    {
        DisableControls(child);
    }
}
```

Now I've hit a problem. If I have (for example) an `<ASP:Panel>` which contains an `<ASP:DropDownList>`, and I want to keep the DropDownList enabled, then this isn't working.

I call DisableControls on the Panel, and it gets disabled. It then loops through the children, and calls DisableControls on the DropDownList, and leaves it enabled (as intended). However, because the Panel is disabled, when the page renders, everything inside the `<div>` tag is disabled!

Can you think of a way round this? I've thought about changing `c.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(WebControl))` to `c.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(SomeParentClassThatAllInputElementsInheritFrom))`, but I can't find anything appropriate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want to disable input controls, so your code is too general. Do something like this:

```
if (IsInputControl(wc) && !wc.CssClass.ToLower().Contains("someclass"))
            wc.Enabled = false;
```

and create function IsInputControl:

```
bool isInputControl(WebControl ctl) {
    if (ctl is TextBox ||
      ctl is DropDownList || 
      ctl is CheckBox ||
      ...) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know of any general property of a WebControl that identifies it as an input control though, but there aren't that many types so it shouldn't be too big a deal to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing something like that... My worry is about getting that list of types correct/complete. If I CAN find a more general method of spotting "input" elements, then I'll do it. If not, then I'll mark yours as the answer :)

Comment: I've done something like this before, I never found one, not to say it doesn't exist. I was doing this for a more general purpose form controller, I ended up creating categories of controls (InputControls, Validators, InputControls_WithHiddenFields). I don't think hidden fields matter for your situation, but they did for mine, and they aren't WebControls (despite being in the System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace) which which makes it even uglier.

Comment: I've ended up doing the inverse of what you suggested. I wrote an "IsContainerControl" function instead... The list of possible containers seems to be shorter than the list of possible input controls! At the moment, I've only excluded Panel controls, but I'm expecting that list to grow as more are identified.